# C# Console Application - Selecting specific records from CSV file and re-writing to new CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, console

I have a C# Console app using a WebClient to read the data from a URL-RPC gateway, then write that data to a CSV file.

I need to, once that CSV file is written (and I'm going to work this like a SQL statement as that's what I'm used to, but I can't use a SQL DB this time around) "Select" all records "Id", "Proctored" and "Score" columns where the "Proctored" column is a string "Yes/Complete", then take those records and write them to a new CSV file.

Any ideas on how to do that easily? I have my basic code below (this code fetches the records from a remote gateway and writes it to a CSV file until I get a "No records found" message. I *cannot* only fetch the columns I want, I have to get all of the data (which includes a few dozen columns) and THEN do the "selecting" on my end.

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient(); //The WebClient calls on the URL-RPC Gateway to get scores
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"); //Header information for WebClient is REQUIRED--this makes it look like our request comes from a browser and allows proper formatting

        string rpcURL; //Initiates the string we'll use to give the WebClient our URL, after adding our parameters
        string s = ""; //This is the string that gets "read" into the CSV file. Initiate this one "" (empty)
        int page = 1; //The page number. Gateway only allows us to call one page at a time (about 200 records.) So we have to check multiple pages until we get no more data returned, instead, we'll get the phrase "No records found"

        while (!s.Contains("No records found")) //When gateway returns "No Records Found" we know we've reached the last page of data we need to get.
        {
            rpcURL = "https://api.WEBSITE.com/urlrpc?method=getPlacementReport&username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&class_code=" + classCode + "&from_date=" + startDate + "&to_date=" + endDate + "&page_num=" + page;
            Console.WriteLine(rpcURL);
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(rpcURL))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                s = sr.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(s);
                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                string docPath = path + "\\" + "AleksReport.csv";

                if (!s.Contains("No records found")) //This makes sure we delete any old file from a previous call to the gateway if it exists
                {
                    if (File.Exists(docPath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(docPath);
                    }
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(docPath))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("End of records");
                }
            }
            page++;

        }
```

Comment: Why are you using WebClient for that? Is for something especial? Because, Microsoft recommends to use HttpClient to make requests

Comment: No particular reason--at least no technical reason. It's a pretty simple API call from a gateway.

Comment: Try [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), so you can use Linq to query your data and write the csv.

Comment: Yes, best idea is to just use a library to do the CSV parsing for you. CSV sounds simple, but there's actually lots of edge cases to consider.

Comment: Can you read this into a list of objects and then use LINQ to query that list? When I say object, I mean some defined type (not an actual Object object)

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks! I've gotten the CsvHelper library added to my solution and I've gotten the class created. Hopefully off to a good start!

Comment: @nollidge I'm quickly finding out JUST how complex CSV can be, considering it's, you know...CSV! I've gotten the CsvHelper library and I've prepared a class for it.

Comment: @berniefitz I suppose I can! Currently trying to use the CsvHelper library to do something similar, I think. Now that I have the class "Score" setup to fetch the records, I'm thinking I can just do a for/while or for each loop in my main program to call upon the scores class, populate the data based on that LINQ query, and then write those back to a new CSV/flatfile, similar to how I have my code going line by line to write the original data from the gateway to the main CSV file, if that makes any sense?

Comment: I was thinking reading the CSV line by line into some List<Score> and then using LINQ to create a new List<Score> and then using CsvHelper to write that new list to a file